# Characters before my first character?

Tags: python, unicode

I have a document that starts with a `1`. However, when I do `repr(contents)`, it gives me some characters before the 1:

```
repr(contents)
'\xef\xbb\xbf1\n'

print contents
1
```

What are these characters for?

Comment: It's the UTF-8 [Byte Order Mark (BOM)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)

Comment: `'\xef\xbb\xbf1\n'.decode('utf-8-sig')`